# How To add single iPad custom view in existing iPhone app running on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I have created an iOS application targeting iPhone. Its not universal application but running on both iPhone and iPad (user can view in 1x and 2x view mode). Now i want to add one single view(xib) for iPad if someone is using the app on ipad and turn the device to landscape mode, is it possible for them to see this custom view? Just the layout would be altered to take advantage of the screen size ?
If its is possible how will I proceed. I am thinking to add a viewcontroller along with Xib targeted for Ipad. This will be added to currentview when it is rotated to landscape orientation and it will be swiped by parent view when it is rotated to portarit mode.

Can i make use of :

```
UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot do that. Turn it into universal.

Comment: If it is an iPhone program, it can't contain an iPad view, even if it is running on an iPad (as effectively it is running in an iPhone simulator).

Comment: @Woody:the iPad view will only be added when its running on iPad but simply discard new custom view on iPhone. Though I am able to do what i've mentioned above(creating view controller with iPad xib) and tested loading it with button action on current view but i want to load it when device is rotated to landscape orientation.

Comment: Why can't you make it a universal app?

Comment: I'm avoiding this deliberately, as app has more than 10 views and if i'll go for universal option, I'll have to modify all these views but the requirement is to change only one

Comment: i think u can make use of UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() and write an if else condition in it.